# How to get TCL list index element using a variable?

Tags: list, indexing, tcl

I have a TCL list

```
   set d_nets { reg0, reg1, reg2, reg3, reg4, reg5, reg6, reg7}
```

I want certain manipulation and get an element. 
Example -

```
  for {set i 0} {$i < 128} {incr i} {
      set new_indx [expr { 7 - $i }]   #expression can be more complicated
      lindex $d_nets $new_indx 
  }
```

However this flags an error

> Error: bad index "....": must be integer?[+-]integer? or end?[+-]integer?

Any help with lindex usage here?

Comment: What version of Tcl are you using? Output of `info patchlevel` command would be good.

Comment: Code works fine for version 8.6.. Just you have to remove that comment "#expression can be more complicated" or you have to change like ";#expression can be more complicated". and Yes version mismatch may be there. Check TCL version with "puts $tcl_version"

Comment: TCL interpreter is part of EDA tool. version 8.5

Answer (score 0):

I'm not getting the error you're getting, but note that you can write

```
lindex $d_nets 7-$i
```

instead of calculating the index value separately.

Apart from needing a semicolon before the quoting `#`, your code works fine here.

You probably want to lose the commas in the list too. Tcl uses whitespace as list separator, so the commas end up in the values.

Comment: No, it doesn't help. May be the difference with TCL version. 'lindex $d_nets 7-$i' gives me error bad index : "7-0" must be integer

Comment: @user2435030: it's surprising that you get an error, since `7-0` is the `integer?[+-]integer?` form that the other error message requested. What version do you have? Is the Tcl interpreter part of some other software?

Comment: Yes TCL interpreter is part of EDA tool. version 8.5

Comment: I know for certain that standard 8.5 accepts the `lindex $list 7-0` syntax. Maybe your tool has redefined the `lindex` command. Sorry, I can't help you.

Comment: Is there any alternative equivalent of lindex in tcl? like array reference??

Comment: You could emulate `lindex` with other list commands, but their indexing is likely to work the same way. Arrays may be the best bet for you.

Answer (score 0):

Hi while adding comments we need to add a semi colon.
After adding the semi colon it is working fine.

% set d_nets { reg0, reg1, reg2, reg3, reg4, reg5, reg6, reg7}

reg0, reg1, reg2, reg3, reg4, reg5, reg6, reg7

%

% for {set i 0} {$i < 128} {incr i} {

```
  set new_indx [expr { 7 - $i }]; #expression can be more complicated

  lindex $d_nets $new_indx
```

}

%

One more option is we can combine both the line in to one as follows.

for {set i 0} {$i < 128} {incr i} {

puts [lindex $d_nets [expr {7-$i}]]

}